# How to do reflexive generic class in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, generics

I am trying to write a generic base class for a Protractor page object. It is a reflexively generic class with an init method that returns itself after waiting or not waiting for angular, depending on whether the object is Angular or not. I want the init method to return the correct type -- the class which extends the base class, but I get a compile error complaining about the fact that I can't return 'this' because it's not an instance of the generic parameter.

```
export abstract class AbstractLoadable<T extends AbstractLoadable<T>> {

    protected isAngularComponent: boolean;

    public constructor(isAngularComponent: boolean = true) {
        this.isAngularComponent = isAngularComponent;
    }

    public initComponent(): T {
        browser.waitForAngularEnabled(this.isAngularComponent);
        if(this.isAngularComponent) {
            browser.waitForAngular();
        }

        return this as T; // Error here.
    }
}
```

The error is: Type '`this`' cannot be converted to type '`T`'. Type '`AbstractLoadable<T>`' is not comparable to type '`T`'.

This pattern works in Java and I am new to JavaScript and typescript. Is it possible to pull this off in Typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike java, typescript has the [polymorphic this type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types) which is very useful in this case:

```
export abstract class AbstractLoadable {
    protected isAngularComponent: boolean;

    public constructor(isAngularComponent: boolean = true) {
        this.isAngularComponent = isAngularComponent;
    }

    public initComponent(): this {
        browser.waitForAngularEnabled(this.isAngularComponent);
        if(this.isAngularComponent) {
            browser.waitForAngular();
        }

        return this;
    }
}
```

As you can see it completely removes the need for generics for this case.
The compiler knows the right class and infers what the return `this` is, so if let's say you have:

```
class MyClass extends AbstractLoadable { ... }
```

Then:

```
let instance = new MyClass().initComponent();
```

Will return a value of type `MyClass`.